# To or For when we want to assign something?

Tags: grammar

I'm going to open a ticket for one IT team to change the volume of the old service called IVO to the new one called INO. And my question is, should I use to or for? The subject will be something like this:
Change 100% of the requests to INO service

Looks good, but what about:
Change 100% of the requests for INO service

I'm not sure, but it looks ok. Which is the right and why?

According to [espresso English](https://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-to-and-for/#:%7E:text=As%20you%20can%20see%20in,York%20for%20a%20new%20job.) site, I should use to because its kind of "Giving", like this one:
I gave the book to my sister

But to be honest, I'm not 100% confident about it.

Comment: Something changes from one thing to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example (*Change 100% of the requests to INO service*) is grammatically correct and understandable ***if*** every request in the system is currently IVO. If not, I would recommend for clarity:

> Change 100% of the IVO requests to INO service.

NOTE: "Change 100% of the requests *for* INO service" indicates that you want to make some change to all the requests that are marked INO, but it is not clear *what* change is to be made to those requests. In other words, my question would be "To what should I change all the requests for INO service?"

Comment: Greate, basically using for is right but it changes the meaning, right? Like "change the structure of request" but in my case, I only want a change from IVO to INO.
Thank you